# Genric object as a parmenter with HandyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, generics, handyjson

I'm using HandyJSON library to convert json to object and i made a static function to do so and it works as i want, here is the code

```
static func objectFromJSONstring<T : HandyJSON>(object: T.Type, JSONString : String) -> T? {
    if let obj = object.deserialize(from: JSONString) {
        return obj
    }
    return nil
}
```

But when i tried to do the same for an Array of objects

```
 static func arrayOfObjectsFromJSONstring<T : HandyJSON>(objt : T.Type, JSONString: String, objectPath: String) -> [T?]? {
        if let obj = [objt].deserialize(from: JSONString) {
        return obj
    }
    return nil
}
```

I get this message : 
Static member 'deserialize' cannot be used on instance of type '[T.Type]'.
I want to know what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it while keeping the same implementation of passing a generic object class as a parameter.

Thanks..

Comment: Where and how is `deserialize(from:)` defined?

Comment: Library called HandyJSON

Answer (score 1):

Just use the generic type parameter `T` instead of the variable to which the argument type is being passed.

```
if let obj = [T].deserialize(from: JSONString) { ... }
```